# Inserting new point from XY Coordinates with field values using ArcPy

Tags: arcpy, arcmap, geometry, cursor, python-2.7

I am trying to add new point from table using XY coordinates fields to database. I can add point without fields, but when i try to add point with field values i can not do it. In SearchCursor **ID** is a field from data table and in InsertCursor **'dazianebis_tipi'** is a field I want to update by **ID** field. Here is code i use:

```
with arcpy.da.SearchCursor("Watersupply_GWP.DBO.%GIS_ACCIDENTS",["PointCoordinateX","PointCoordinateY","ID"])as cursor:
             for row in cursor:
                 point.X = row[0]
                 point.Y = row[1]
                 req_ID  = row[2]
                 
                 rowValues = [[req_ID,((point_Geometry_out.centroid.X),( point_Geometry_out.centroid.Y))]]
                 
                 cur = arcpy.da.InsertCursor(fcc,['dazianebis_tipi','SHAPE@XY'])
                 for row in rowValues:
                     cur.insertRow(row)
```

Comment: Even if you ran your code from the Python window of ArcMap, please remove the ellipses at the beginning of each line so that the code you present can be copy/pasted for easier testing by any potential answerers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have just used double quotes for field `dazianebis_tipi` in `InsertCursor` and it works perfect now:

```
with arcpy.da.SearchCursor("Watersupply_GWP.DBO.%GIS_ACCIDENTS",["PointCoordinateX","PointCoordinateY","ID"])as cursor:
     for row in cursor:
         point.X = row[0]
         point.Y = row[1]
         req_ID = row[2]
                 
         rowValues = [[req_ID,((point_Geometry_out.centroid.X),( point_Geometry_out.centroid.Y))]]
         #xy = ["SHAPE@X","SHAPE@Y"]
         cur = arcpy.da.InsertCursor(fcc,["dazianebis_tipi","SHAPE@XY"])
         for row in rowValues:
             cur.insertRow(row)
```